# Выходит ошибка в void main()

Tags: c++

) Создать абстрактный тип данных (структура) - вектор, который имеет указатель на double
и число элементов. Определить функции: инициализации, удаления вектора,
установки/изменения размера, доступа к элементам вектора, вычисления суммы четных
элементов вектора. Для примера, в функции main, организовать сложение вектора и числа.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <math.h>
     using namespace std;
    struct Vector{
        double *x;
        int n;        
    };
     
    int getN (Vector *v){
        return v->n;
    }
     
    void setN (Vector *v, int nr){
        if (nr<1) v->n=1;
            else v->n=nr;
    }
     
    short getX (Vector *v, int pos){
        if ((pos>=0)&&(pos<getN(v)))
            return v->x[pos];
        cout << "Position Error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
     
    void setX (Vector *v, int pos, double value){
        if ((pos>=0)&&(pos<getN(v)))
            v->x[pos]=value;
        else cout << "Position Error" << endl;
    }
     
    void initVector(Vector *v,int max){
        setN(v,max);
        double *ptr=new double[v->n];
        v->x=ptr;
        for (int i=0; i<v->n; i++)
            v->x[i]=0;
    }
     
    void deleteVector (Vector *v){
        delete[] v->x;
        v->n=NULL;
    }
     
    short SumPar (Vector *v){
        double sum=0;
        for (int i=1; i<getN(v); i+=2)
            sum+=getX(v,i);
        return sum;
    }
     
    double Norma (Vector *v){
        double sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<getN(v); i++)
            sum+=getX(v,i)*getX(v,i);
        return sqrtf(sum);
    }
     
    void main()
    {
        Vector *tab;
        int N,num;
        short val;
        
     
        cout << "Dati numarul de vectori: ";
        cin >> N;
        if (N==0) ;
        tab = new Vector[N];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            cout << "dati numarul de elemente a vectorului " << (i+1) << ": ";
            cin >> num;
            initVector(&tab[i], num);
            cout << "dati elementele: ";
            for (int j=0; j<getN(&tab[i]); j++){
                cin >> val;
                setX(&tab[i],j,val);
            }
        }
        
    
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            cout << "v" << (i+1) << ": ";
            for (int j=0; j<getN(&tab[i]); j++)
                cout << getX(&tab[i],j) << " ";
            cout << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            cout << "\ns" << (i+1) << "=" << SumPar(&tab[i]);
     
    
        cout << "\ncare 2 vectori doriti sa comparati?" << endl;
        int v1,v2;
        double n1,n2;
        cin >> v1 >> v2;
        if (v1<=0||v1>N||v2<=0||v2>N) 
            cout << "\nEroare. Nu exista astfel de vectori\n";
        else {
            n1=Norma(&tab[v1-1]);
            n2=Norma(&tab[v2-1]);
            if (n1>n2) {
                cout << "v" << v1 << " > v" << v2 << endl;
                cout << n1 << " > " << n2 << endl;
                }
            else if (n1==n2){
                    cout << "v" << v1 << " = v" << v2 << endl;
                    cout << n1 << " = " << n2 << endl;
                    }
                else {
                    cout << "v" << v1 << " < v" << v2 << endl;
                    cout << n1 << " < " << n2 << endl;
                    }
            }
            
    
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
            deleteVector(&tab[i]);
    getch();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [`main` должен `int` возвращать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Comment: Где текст ошибки?

Comment: добавил текст ошибки

Comment: if (N==0)  { return; }
        tab = new Vector[N];

Comment: перевод : [ошибка] команда return без значения в функции, возвращающей 'int' [флаг по стандарту] *(Ошибки вы должны показать текстом. У вас шрифт оччень малленький.)* Решение : `return 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Странные дела начинаются с `short getX (Vector *v, int pos)` — почему, если у вас вектор `double`, вы возвращаете `short`, а не `double`?

Аналогично, если у вас

```
double sum=0;
...
return sqrtf(sum);
```

и функция возвращает `double`, зачем же вычислять `sqrtf`, а не `sqrt`?...

```
void main()
```

неверно, нужен

```
int main()
```

Непонятно также

```
if (N==0) ;
```

И что вы хотите этим сказать? Кстати, на скриншоте у вас `int main()` и `return` после `if (N==0)`, а *вот это* уже проблема: раз `main` возвращает `int`, то и `return` должен быть со значением, `return 0;`, например.

Вот все, что найдено компилятором. Правильно ли ваш код *работает*, а не компилируется — вопрос другой, не смотрел... Но даже навскидку:

```
void setN (Vector *v, int nr){
    if (nr<1) v->n=1;
    else v->n=nr;
}
```

Как я понимаю, это изменение размера (количества элементов) в векторе? Тогда почему вы не меняете выделенную память? А то ведь запросто может быть, что вы выделили 5 элементов, а потом сделали `n` сотней, и здравствуй, выход за пределы массива...